# Multiple Image upload to S3 using dropzone

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

Uploading Image to AWS S3 using [dropzone js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

```
    Dropzone.prototype.submitRequest = function(xhr, formData, files) {
       return xhr.send(formData);
    };
```

xhr is object of XMLHttpRequest.

formData consist of :

1. Signature
2. Unique Image Path
3. File

S3 is configured to accept one image per request.

**Challenge** :

Modify dropzone to send separate requests for multiple files selected at once by client side.